# How to take a median of all the values greater than a certain number if the data is stored in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to use `np.median()` to take the median of all the values greater than a certain value (50 in my case). How do I go about it?

Comment: In an array. Will edit the question.

Comment: [Aside: please put useful information like that in the question itself, not the title.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way. I can't say if it is the best way:

```
In [14]: a=np.array([1,5,10,25,50,75,100])

In [15]: a>50
Out[15]: array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [16]: a[a>50]
Out[16]: array([ 75, 100])

In [17]: np.median(a[a>50])
Out[17]: 87.5
```

Comment: This is it. Additionally, would it be possible to take a median of values within a certain range?

Comment: Try  `np.median(a[(a > 20) & (a < 80)])` or `np.median(a[np.logical_and(a > 20, a < 80)])`.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in a list l, then do

```
np.median([val for val in l if val > 50])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
a = np.array([23, 50, 100, 120])
np.median(a[a > 50])
```